# Add amount in mysql with a certain limit

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL query

```
update `table_1` 
set `amount` = `amount` + 120 
where `id` = 1;
```

If I run this multiple time will add amount.
Can I set the `amount` column to a certain amount like 1000?

Means amount will not be added when it comes 1000

Comment: something like `where id = 1 and amount <= 1000`

Comment: i would do with the same id

As i want with this id maximum amount should 1000

Comment: If you are looking for the database to be protected against it, then look at triggers.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `LEAST()` function to put a cap on the amount.

```
UPDATE table_1
SET amount = LEAST(amount + 120, 1000)
WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: I would add `and amount != 1000` to the where

Comment: Why would that be needed? I could add `AND amount <= 1000`, so if it's already over the cap we won't subtract.